# How to prove $\frac{\pi}{4 \Gamma^2(1.5)} =1$?

Tags: analysis, gamma-function

I obtained the following identity, by numerical analysis. $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function. How can I analytically show this?

\begin{equation}
\frac{\pi}{4 \Gamma^2(1.5)} =1
\end{equation}

Answer (score 6):

See [here](https://jekyll.math.byuh.edu/courses/m321/handouts/gammahalf.pdf) for proof that $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$.

Then apply that $\Gamma(z+1)=z \Gamma(z)$.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot!